# Checking sftp connection status and try another IP if failed

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

What I am try to do is to send file via a sftp using a shell script. I try connecting to a first IP and if this connection fail, I try another one.
Problem is, I can't seem to catch the sftp status.

Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp -oIdentityFile=path_to_private_key  USER@IP1:PATH <<EOF
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        put myfile
        ls
        quit
else
        echo "ERROR"
fi
EOF
```

do you have any idea how to makes something like that work:

```
sftp IP1
if(success){
   put file
   quit
}
else{
   sftp IP2
   if(success2){
      put file
      quit
   }
   else{
      echo "Error"
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do what I wanted. The problem was as I suspected around the "EOF / if"

Here's what I found :

```
#!/bin/bash
sftp -oIdentityFile=path_to_private_key USER@$IP1:PATH <<-EOF1
        put myfile
        quit
EOF1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    sftp -oIdentityFile=path_to_private_key USER@$IP2:PATH <<-EOF2
        put myfile
        quit
    -EOF2
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR"
    fi
fi
```

Hope it will help anyone who had this problem